# Stop creating a new aov pass if with the same name exist already

Tags: python, render-passes

```
import bpy

aovname = bpy.context.active_object.active_material.name
ntree = bpy.context.object.active_material.node_tree

mat = bpy.context.active_object.active_material

if mat.use_nodes == True:
    nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
    if 'AOV Output' in mat.node_tree.nodes:
        print ("It exist")

    else:
        node = ntree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeOutputAOV').name = aovname


listofaov = bpy.context.scene.view_layers['View Layer'].aovs

for x in listofaov:
    if aovname in listofaov:
        print ("hello")
        
    else:
        bpy.ops.scene.view_layer_add_aov()
        bpy.context.scene.name = aovname
        bpy.context.scene.view_layers['View Layer'].active_aov.name = aovname
```

I'm setting up a script for Blender 2.93.0 that creates an aov output node with the material's name and at the same time creates an aov pass with the same name, the problem is that the script should stop creating a new aov pass if there is already one with the same name.

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning `scene.view_layer_add_aov` is only available in recent versions of API (2.92 or .93)   If you are going to declare a variable _eg_ above `mat` .. then use it in code  going forward. Also consider using get,  `node = nodes.get(name) or nodes.new(type)`

Comment: @batFINGER  Thanks for the advice.
I have managed to create a loop and it works as long as there is an aov pass but if the list is empty the script is not creating a new aov pass, what could be the reason for this? I have updated my code.